# React Native Render HTML bullet list is not centered with text

Tags: django, react-native, django-ckeditor

I'm using [react-native-render-html library](https://github.com/meliorence/react-native-render-html) to display data from Django Rest Framework stored in `RichTextUploadingField` from `django-ckeditor`. As basic styling is working properly I have a problem with the `<ul>` tag - text is not centered with circle/square/number as shown in the image. I tried using `renderersProps` like:

```
<RenderHTML renderersProps={{ ul: { markerBoxStyle:{ paddingRight: 3, top: 5 }, markerTextStyle: { color: "red" } } }} />
```

But it works for specific text size. If I change the text size in style in Django admin, the element and text aren't centered again. Is there any option on how to fix it or what causes the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could add a custom CSS class to unordered list items only. Then apply your styles to that CSS class.

```js
// this function goes through every list item in <ul> only and adds your custom class ('ul-li' in my case)
const onElement = (el) => {
  const { children, name } = el;
  if (name === 'ul' && children && children.length) {
      children.forEach(listItem => listItem.attribs = {class: 'ul-li'})
  }
}

// define your styles for your custom class
const classesStyles = {
  "ul-li": {
    lineHeight: '21px', // for me adjusting lineHeight did the job
  }
}

// in your JSX
<RenderHtml
  source={source}
  contentWidth={width}
  tagsStyles={tagsStyles}
  ... // other props you may have
  domVisitors={{onElement}} // first alter your html
  classesStyles={classesStyles} // then apply styles
/>
```

Sources:
[classesstyles](https://meliorence.github.io/react-native-render-html/api/stylesconfig#classesstyles)
[onElement](https://meliorence.github.io/react-native-render-html/api/domvisitorcallbacks#onelement)